# Updating value of tuple in a set in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Currently I have code which takes in a set of tuples each having the format (A,B). Over the course of the set, each A has a multiple B's which it is linked to. I want to create another set that contains tuples of the format (A, B1, B2, B3) where B1, B2, B3, etc. are values of B associated with A in the first set. Currently I have this code:

```
data_set = set(tuple(x) for x in data) #converts given list of lists to set of tuples
association = set() #empty set to add (A, B1, B2, etc.) tuples
    for j in data_set: #loop through data set
        if (j[0]) not in association:
            associaton.add((j[0])) #This makes the first value of of my new tuple the value I want to find
        else:
           #I want to replace the current tuple with the current tuple plus the value of j[1]
```

How could I find the correct tuple in association to update. I plan on updating a tuple A by using A = A + (j[1]).

Comment: `tuples` are immutable... i.e. you cannot change it.  You can use `list(x)` instead.

Comment: `(j[0])` isn't a tuple; it's just `j[0]` in grouping parentheses. `(j[0],)` would be a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll lean out of the window and claim that you're describing a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

It looks like `tuple` is not the data structure you are looking for. If you have a list of tuples of the form `(A, B)` and want to group them by their first item, you could use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries) like this:

```
association = {}  # empty dictionary
for j in data_set:
    if j[0] not in association:
        association[j[0]] = []  # initialize empty list
    association[j[0]].append(j[1])
```

If your input data was `(A, B1), (A, B2), (A, B3)`, the result will be `{A: [B1, B2, B3]}`.

The above code can be cleared up a bit using tuple unpacking:

```
association = {}  # empty dictionary
for key, value in data_set:
    if key not in association:
        association[key] = []  # initialize empty list
    association[key].append(value)
```

Comment: You could use a `collections.defaultdict` with a `list`: `association = defaultdict(list)` which would remove the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value inside of a tuple, but what you can do is making it a list and making it a tuple after. Something like this:

```
tupl = ("a", "b", "c")
tupl = list(tupl)   # will change it to a list: ["a", "b", "c"]
tupl.append("d")    # appends "d" to the list
tupl = tuple(tupl)  # changes it back to a tuple ("a", "b", "c", "d")
```